# How to delete a record only if it exists in Rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to delete the tokens I created for a post, when I am deleting the post itself. But if the token does not exist, I don't want Rails to throw an error and stop executing.

Right now, this is how I go about it. I think this code is way too chunky. Is there any neat way to accomplish the same?

```
DownloadToken.find_by_post_id(post.id).destroy unless DownloadToken.find_by_post_id(@post.id).nil?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at your Post model; post.rb

Ie.

```
Class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :download_tokens, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Now when you delete a Post object, whatever the association; `has_many`, `has_one`, it will find the destroy the `dependent` also.  In this case the DownloadToken(s)

Comment: Actually If you `delete` a post, nothing will happen to the tokens, because the `dependent: destroy` hook is triggered only from the `destroy` method.

Comment: This is a good point; To be more clear, this answer assumes you will also be calling the `destroy` method on a Post object

Answer (score 16):

This is one way(old syntax)

```
DownloadToken.find_by_post_id(post.id).try(:destroy)
```

Newer syntax in rails:

```
DownloadToken.find_by(id: post.id).try(:destroy)
```

With Ruby's safe navigation operator:

```
DownloadToken.find_by(id: post.id)&.destroy
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DownloadToken.find_by_post_id(post.id)&.destroy
```

Executes `destroy` only if the query result is not `nil`. It's the abbreviated version of:

```
token = DownloadToken.find_by_post_id(post.id)
token.destroy if token
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are certain you 'll handle the `post` deletion with its `destroy` method, than you can follow [Jay's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28039544/687142) and it will work just fine.

If you will use the `delete` method on `post` you need some extra functionality to handle the `download_tokens`.

```
class DownloadToken < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.remove_post_tokens(the_post_id)
    where(post_id: the_post_id).destroy_all
  end
end
```

so your sequence will be:

```
id = post.id
post.delete #or post.destroy
DownloadToken.remove_post_tokens(id)
```

That scenario is not purely academic, because the dependent destroy action can be really expensive, eg if you have too many download_tokens, so you would not want it to be in the same transaction as `post`'s destruction.